# .htaccess rewrite works but 503 redirect fails

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**Background**

We, a group of whisky enthusiasts, only release a new whisky cask plan (product) once a week at Wednesdays at 1900 CET and since the demand to obtain a share in the casks exceeds the availability by many times, the server is more or less rampaged at 1900 CET and can thus do with all the server resources available.

**Preferred Solution**

After analyzing the logs of the last weeks I noticed that many of the > 800 members are also active simultaneously on the forum at the time of the release of the new cask plan (product). So to ease the load for the server a bit I want to make the forum temporarily unavailable between 1855 and 1915 CET, every Wednesday.

So I came up with the following code for the .htaccess to control this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum(/.*|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/timeline(/.*|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =3
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >1654
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1715
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /503-Wednesday-1900CET.php [R=503,L]
```

Some notes:

- I also include the `/timeline/` pages, just to be sure, as it uses a bit heavier query. So I want to exlude the possibility that the cache is refreshed during this window.
- TIME_WDAY starts with Sunday at 0 so to just pass this condition on Wednesday `=3`.
- The server is configured with the UTC timezone so I have to adjust for the timezone
  offset which results in `>1654` and `<1715`, instead of `>1854` and `<1915`.

I can test the above, without the 3 `RewriteCond %{TIME_` lines, successfully on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

But when I try it on my server, with the 3 `RewriteCond %{TIME_` lines **disabled**, it results in a **503** message from the server but it doesn't actually rewrites the url to the `/503-Wednesday-1900CET.php` file...

When I try it on my server, with the 3 `RewriteCond %{TIME_` lines **enabled**, it results in a **500** message from the server and also doesn't actually rewrites the url to the `/503-Wednesday-1900CET.php` file...

**My Questions**

What might be the reason that the `/503-Wednesday-1900CET.php` file isn't served? I suspect the RewriteRule contains something the server doesn't accept but I don't see it.

And what might be the reason that the 3 `RewriteCond %{TIME_` lines result in a 500 error message instead?

I already searched the web and Stackoverflow but I don't seem to find the trick to get me forward with this. So any hint is welcome at the moment.

Comment: What webserver/version are you running?

Comment: 503 is _not_ a redirection. It is an error statement.

Comment: @MrWhite it's a website hosted at one.com. It an Apache server but they removed the version in the server vars but I believe it's version 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can test the above, without the 3 RewriteCond %{TIME_ lines, successfully on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

The MWL tester tool is incorrect. When you specify a return status outside the 3xx range then the *substitution* string is ignored and the error document for the respective status code is served instead (or default server response if an `ErrorDocument` has not been explicitly defined). So, you need to define a custom `ErrorDocument` for the 503 status.

Not sure why you'd be getting a 500 error as there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the directives you've posted, other than that mentioned above.

However, you do have to be careful that the error document itself does not trigger a 503 response - as this would result in an endless loop (500 error). You also have to be careful that any linked resources (images, CSS, etc.) are not also blocked. (Although you've not got so far as serving your error document yet).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 503 /503-Wednesday-1900CET.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/forum(/.*|$) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/timeline(/.*|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} =3
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >1654
RewriteCond %{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} <1715
RewriteRule !^503 - [R=503]
```

Note that the *substitution string* in the `RewriteRule` directive is just a single hyphen (`-`) - indicating no substitution (it's ignored anyway).

The `!^503` pattern is to ensure that the error document itself does not result in a 503 response (effectively an endless loop, that would result in the server's default error response with an additional message along the lines of "a 500 error was encountered trying to serve an ErrorDocument to handle the request".) Likewise, you will need to make sure that any linked resources are not also caught by this rule. It is generally preferable to have the 503 response as basic as possible.

You don't need the `L` flag when specifying a status code outside of the 3xx range.

I removed the `RewriteBase /` directive since it's not required here. However, if you have other directives that rely on this then obviously add it back.

Strictly speaking a 503 response should also come with a `Retry-After` HTTP response header containing the time the service is expected to return. (I assume you are setting this in your PHP script.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and the solution! I learned something AND it's working now :)

And yes, the `Retry-After` HTTP response header is already in the php script of the page with the message.